# QRCode.net (from CodePlex) always replaces first character with an asterisk?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, qr-code

Using QRCode.net assembly to generate QRCode images for URLs, I've tried most of the properties / options available and the URLs first character is always replaced with an asterisk (*). As the QRCode text is to be a URL, this means that some QRCode reader apps don't recognise my QRCode as a valid URL. For now, I pad the URL with a ' ' space so you at least get '*http://myapp.com', instead of '*ttp://myapp.com', but this always happens..

[QRCode.Net on CodePlex](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com)

Has anyone seen this before, or know which setting stops it, I've tried most, here's my code:

```
Dim iee As New ImageEncoder()
        iee.AutoConfigurate = True
        iee.ECI = -1
        iee.Encoding = 4
        iee.Fnc1Mode = 0
        iee.ErrorCorrectionLevel = 0
        iee.Version = 1
        iee.ProcessTilde = False
        iee.MarginSize = 10
        iee.ModuleSize = 6
        iee.StructuredAppend = False
        iee.StructuredAppendCounter = 0
        iee.StructuredAppendIndex = 0
        iee.TextData = " http://myApp.com/?querystringdata=here")
        Dim image As Bitmap = iee.Encode2Image()
        Dim tempSitePath As String
        tempSitePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Session("dirTempPath"))
        image.Save(tempSitePath + "loc_" + locid + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was bugged with them.. Ended up using a different library..

Answer (score 0):

I found a demo library for QRCode.net.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258779/Just-launched-new-open-source-project-QrCode-Net-a

This has downloadable source-code.  I opened the solution, made a few changes to get the project to build and it created codes with no asterisk (*).  I believe the demo code is older than this post, but perhaps the library has also been updated with a fix.